# Loop with subelements filter

Tags: ansible, fortigate

Variable:

```yaml
customers:
  - name: CompanyX
    destination_addresses:
      - 192.168.0.0/24
      - 192.168.1.0/24

  - name: CompanyY
    destination_addresses:
      - 192.168.2.0/24
      - 192.168.3.0/24
```

I'm trying to create address objects for each address in destination_addresses, and create an address group object that stores all addresses per customer.
The creation of each address works as expected like this:

```yaml
- name: add address object for destination networks
  fortinet.fortios.fortios_firewall_address:
    state: present
    firewall_address:
      name: "{{ item.0.name }}-{{ item.1 }}"
      subnet: "{{ item.1 }}"
  loop: "{{ customers | subelements('destination_addresses') }}"
```

This creates:

- `CompanyX-192.168.0.0/24`
- `CompanyX-192.168.1.0/24`
- `CompanyY-192.168.2.0/24`
- `CompanyY-192.168.3.0/24`

But I'm struggling how to group the address objects.
This is what I use now:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    grp_members: "{{ grp_members | default([]) + [{ 'name': item.0.name ~ '-' ~ item.1 }] }}"
  loop: "{{ customers | subelements('destination_addresses') }}"
  loop_control:
    extended: yes

- name: create address group
  fortinet.fortios.fortios_firewall_addrgrp:
    state: present
    firewall_addrgrp:
      name: "{{ item.name }}"
      member: "{{ grp_members }}"
  loop: "{{ customers }}"
```

Which creates the group **CompanyX** and **CompanyY** but with all addresses in each group, because the `grp_members` variable contains all addresses.
How can I limit the group members to only contain the addresses for CompanyX & CompanyY separately?

Current output:

```yaml
- debug:
    var: grp_members

    "grp_members": [
        {
            "name": "CompanyX-192.168.0.0/24"
        },
        {
            "name": "CompanyX-192.168.1.0/24"
        },
        {
            "name": "CompanyY-192.168.2.0/24"
        },
        {
            "name": "CompanyY-192.168.3.0/24"
        }
    ]
```

Desired result for each customer:

```yaml
    "grp_members": [
        {
            "name": "CompanyX-192.168.0.0/24"
        },
        {
            "name": "CompanyX-192.168.1.0/24"
        }
    ]
```

```yaml
    "grp_members": [
        {
            "name": "CompanyY-192.168.2.0/24"
        },
        {
            "name": "CompanyY-192.168.3.0/24"
        }
    ]
```

The fortinet.fortios.fortios_firewall_addrgrp module expects a dictionary in the above syntax.

Comment: Hi, please see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or add a simple desired output. I couldn't test your playbook or understand your goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the changed conditions you need the following:

```yaml
- name: create address group
  fortinet.fortios.fortios_firewall_addrgrp:
    state: present
    firewall_addrgrp:
      name: "{{ item.name }}"
      member: "{{ grp_members }}"
  vars:
    grp_members: "{{ [item.name] | product(item.destination_addresses) | map('join', '-') | map('community.general.dict_kv', 'name') }}"
  loop: "{{ customers }}"
```

You continue iterating over `customers`. The variable `grp_members` is generated locally for each iteration.

1. via `product` a cross product of the customer with each IP is created
2. via `join` the two elements customer name and IP are connected.
3. `dict_kv` creates a dict from the list with the key `name`.

*You don't need your task with `set_fact` anymore.*

---

Here you can see the sample output of the joined addresses.

This task

```yaml
- name: generate kv dict with customer-address
  debug:
    msg: "{{ grp_members }}"
  vars:
    grp_members: "{{ [item.name] | product(item.destination_addresses) | map('join', '-') | map('community.general.dict_kv', 'name') }}"
  loop: "{{ customers }}"
```

produces this output

```
TASK [generate kv dict with customer-address] *******************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'CompanyX', 'destination_addresses': ['192.168.0.0/24', '192.168.1.0/24']}) => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "name": "CompanyX-192.168.0.0/24"
        },
        {
            "name": "CompanyX-192.168.1.0/24"
        }
    ]
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'CompanyY', 'destination_addresses': ['192.168.2.0/24', '192.168.3.0/24']}) => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "name": "CompanyY-192.168.2.0/24"
        },
        {
            "name": "CompanyY-192.168.3.0/24"
        }
    ]
}
```

---

#### old post

I think that's what you're looking for.

```yaml
- name: create address group
  fortinet.fortios.fortios_firewall_addrgrp:
    state: present
    firewall_addrgrp:
      name: "{{ item.name }}"
      member: "{{ item.destination_addresses | join(',') }}"
  loop: "{{ customers }}"
```

I guess that `member` should be all addresses of the respective customer? These are in a list for the respective customer and you can join them to a string via [`join` function](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#manipulating-strings).

So the task `set_fact` for `grp_members` would not be necessary.

*If this is not the result you need, you have to describe it exactly.*

---

Here you can see the sample output of the joined addresses.

This task

```yaml
- name: Iterate over customers.
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item.name }}: {{ item.destination_addresses | join(',') }}"
  loop: "{{ customers }}"
```

produces this output

```
TASK [Iterate over customers.] ***************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'CompanyX', 'destination_addresses': ['192.168.0.0/24', '192.168.1.0/24']}) => {
    "msg": "CompanyX: 192.168.0.0/24,192.168.1.0/24"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'CompanyY', 'destination_addresses': ['192.168.2.0/24', '192.168.3.0/24']}) => {
    "msg": "CompanyY: 192.168.2.0/24,192.168.3.0/24"
}
```

Comment: Awesome, that's exactly the solution I had, but couldn't post it, because the expected result isn't clear in the question.

Comment: Apologies for not being clear about the desired result, I have edited my question.
The given reply is not what I'm looking for, the module expects a dictionary in the "name: value" format (also described in the question now).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I have added to my post above. — I would be very happy about an up-vote and if my answer provides the solution to your problem, I would be happy if you accept my answer. ([How does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers))